# When does windows HNS rely on Hyper-V, and how can you determine HNS functionality that is Hyper-v dependent?

Tags: windows, networking, kubernetes

Documentation for HNS generally has several references to Hyper-V as a service, for example:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture , refers to creation of a "Hyper-V virtual switch for each network."

Different networking solutions in the Docker and Kubernetes networking model may or may not rely, specifically, on Hyper-V running.   In Kubernetes, there is alot of use of HNS

- the kube-proxy uses HNS to create routing rules
- calico, a CNI provider, creates new network firewall rules (https://github.com/projectcalico/node/blob/master/windows-packaging/CalicoWindows/node/node-service.ps1) and then creates a new `HNSNetwork` (presumably, this does not need Hyper-V, as there is no requirement for hyper-v in calico documentation).

So my overall question is:

- Does HNS, ever, require Hyper-V for its functionality, and if so, how can you know wether an HNS operation will or will not work due to hyper-v installation and enablement?

The relevance of this overall question is that, on public clouds (like AWS, for example) or nested virtualization environments (common for testing or local development against technologies like vsphere and NSX), its often the case that you may want to run windows containers in lightweight VMs which do not in any way enable Hyper-V as a service due to the fact that they are nested, and nested virtualization is disabled by default in many places.

Comment: The link to the documentation is broken.

Comment: fixed the link, thanks for noting https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/architecture